# AppSheet: adding new data populates a ' in the cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-appsheet

This is happening on several sheets and I'm not sure what would cause it (and I can't find anything online about it).
What in AppSheet would cause the cells of new data to populate a ' at the beginning of the cell's value?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Google Sheets the apostrophe is used to force a value to be parsed as TEXT instead of any other data types like NUMBER (including Date, Duration, Time, etc) and BOOLEAN.

If you don't find any place you app in AppSheet that explicitly adds the apostrophe, look what might be generating the value. In this case the problem apparently occurs in an auto calculated column. Take a look to the settings of this column and to whatever might modify its values.